# How to install libxcb-randr 1.12 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, 17.04, source-packages, rust

Ubuntu 16.04 (16.04.4) ppa contains only 1.11. But for Rust program compilation i need 1.12 version. How to deal with it ?

P.s. 17.04 contains xcb v.1.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Uninstall libxcb-randr0.

   ```
   sudo apt remove libxcb-randr0
   ```
2. Manually download libxcb-randr0 (1.12-1ubuntu1) from the official Ubuntu 17.10 repositories from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libxcb-randr0).

   - Under the **Download libxcb-randr0** section click either the red amd64 link or the i386 link, depending on your OS's architecture.
   - Select a nearby mirror and download libxcb-randr0.
3. Open the terminal, and change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the libxcb-randr0_1.12-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb file that you downloaded.
4. Install libxcb-randr0_1.12-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb with this command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libxcb-randr0_1.12-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb # the i386 .deb file has a different name
   ```
5. Run `sudo apt-mark hold libxcb-randr0` which will prevent libxcb-randr0 from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.